# Как различить значения объекта и предиката для местоимения «нечего» при переводе?

Tags: словоупотребление

По теме вопроса: [https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/what-is-the-difference-between-нечего-and-ничего](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/what-is-the-difference-between-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-and-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Меня заинтересовала эта тема. В ответе говорилось, что «нечего» – это **предикат**, в отличие от «ничего», которое  является объектом. Но это не показалось мне справедливым, я полагаю, что в русском языке «нечего» обычно тоже  **объект**, но в частном случае может быть **предикатом**.

Но главное – это проблема с переводом текста на английский язык.

1. *Нечего говорить* (не надо говорить) – это предикат, *нечего сказать* (нет информации)  – это объект. В русском языке **смысл разный**.

Работаю с переводчиком, но в обоих случаях получаю **одинаковый результат**: ***nothing to say***.

2. Составляю предложения на эту тему. *Нечего говорить, если не знаешь. Ему нечего сказать.* Переводчик сообщает: *There's nothing to say if you don't know. He has nothing to say.* Первое предложение мне кажется **неверным**.
3. Делаю замену: не надо говорить, если не знаешь. Получаю: Don't tell me if you don't know.
4. И какой вывод? Переводчик узнает только **объектное значение,**  а предикат переводит **неверно или неточно**? А как же тогда перевести «нечего говорить» в значении «не надо (не следует)  говорить»?

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В знак благодарности за ответы и ваше внимание добавлю немного полезной **информации на эту тему.**

В русском языке предложения с местоимением «нечего» относятся  к особой группе **односоставных** предложений (с одним главным членом, обычно сказуемым). Такие предложения называются «**безлично-инфинитивными»**.

Их **структура** такова: инфинитив, местоимение (с отрицанием или без отрицания) и связка «быть» при необходимости.

**Примеры:**  Нечего читать. Нечего было читать. Есть что почитать. Будет о чем поговорить.

**В толковом словаре** для местоимения «нечего» в значения предиката дается указание  **на разговорный стиль и модальное значение**: не приходится, не следует; не полагается; нет смысла, не нужно; незачем.

**Примеры**

Начнем с А.С.Пушкина: В молчании добро должно твориться. Но ***нечего*** об этом толковать.

**Другие примеры:** Нечего надеяться на помощь.  Ей нечего меня стыдиться. Нечего стоять под дождём. Нечего заранее волноваться.  Хорош, нечего сказать! (неодобр., значение объекта, сов. вид).  Нечего и говорить (выражение согласия).

Comment: Может ли это быть связано с аспектом глагола?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*нечего* in the sense of "nothing to": *нечего надеть, нечего сказать* etc. can only be used with a verb which governs the accusative or genitive and accepts an inanimate object.

*нечего* in the sense of "no need to, no use to": *нечего сдаваться, нечего беспокоиться* can only be used with an imperfective verb.

With an imperfective verb which governs accusative or genitive of an inanimate object, there is no way to tell the exact the role of *нечего* just from the structure of the sentence.

*Нечего бояться* could mean both "there is no use in being afraid" and "there is nothing to be afraid of".

Comment: Благодарю вас за прекрасный ответ и помощь в переводе. В русском языке при различении предиката и объекта можно ориентироваться на модальное значение предиката и дополнительно на контекст. Но ваши указания на грамматические значения были мне очень интересны.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a good example would be

**Нечего** (предикат) **говорить**(always imperfective infinitive) , **если нечего** (местоимение) **сказать**.

Possible translations are

Keep your mouth shut/ don't speak/ you shouldn't speak, etc.
if you have nothing to say.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш пример!